# Boot into a chroot?

Tags: directory, startup, chroot

I have Linux (Debian Jessie) installed on a hard drive. Drive - `sda1`, ext4fs, and `sda2` - swap

I have a `/chroot` folder. There is installed another system, in `/chroot` folder.

Question:

How to tell the bootmanager, to boot *not the primary system* (main, Debian Jessie), but system in */chroot*? Probably, change `/menu.lst` and `/chroot/etc/fstab`? (`vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1/chroot`?)

Or another variant of question: is it possible, to have linux installed not into root directory of partition, but in folder? (`/another_linux/bin`, `/another_linux/home`, `/another_linux/etc`, ...)

Comment: `vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1/chroot` won't work. One probably could simulate this with a method similar to what is used in `initrd`. See e.g. [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/initrd.txt). You mount `/new_root` as described there, then instead of `cd /new_root` do `cd /new_root/chroot` and continue.

Answer (score 9):

I came across the same issue and ended up [writing this](https://github.com/lemonsqueeze/boot_chroot) to make it work painlessly across different systems (debian, ubuntu currently):

Run `make_chroot_initrd` script to create a new chroot-enabled initrd image from the existing one:

```
#  ./make_chroot_initrd /chroot/trusty/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
making new initrd: /chroot/trusty/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic.chroot
```

The new image will be exactly the same, except now it can handle a `chroot=` boot parameter.

With grub2 as bootloader you can add an entry to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`:
(or perhaps better `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`)

```
menuentry "ubuntu trusty, (linux 3.13.0-32) (chroot)" {
    insmod ext2                       # or whatever you're using ...
    set root='(hd0,7)'                # partition containing the chroot
    set chroot='/chroot/trusty'       # chroot path
    linux   $chroot/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=/dev/sda7 chroot=$chroot rw
    initrd  $chroot/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic.chroot
}
```

(change files/partitions to match yours)

#### System-wide install

Once you're happy with it you can make the changes permanent
(until initramfs-tools package gets upgraded).
In the chrooted system:

```
# cd /usr/share/initramfs-tools
# cp -pdrv .  ../initramfs-tools.orig       # backup
# patch -p1 < path_to/boot_chroot/initrd.patch
# rm *.orig */*.orig
# update-initramfs -u
```

From now on regular initrd image will support chroot booting.
No need to use a separate initrd.chroot which may get out of sync with it then.

See [boot_chroot](https://github.com/lemonsqueeze/boot_chroot) for details.

Answer (score 8):

This cannot be done by the bootloader or kernel. The parameter to the kernel `root` option such as in `root=/dev/sda1` looks like a standard Unix pathname, but such pathnames are interpreted according to currently mounted filesystem. At the time the `root` option is interpreted, **there are no** mounted filesystems. Well, almost none. At kernel initialization time there is an instance of a minimal `ramfs` filesystem called `rootfs` mounted as the root for the initial process running `start_kernel()`. The actual interpretation of the `root` option parameter is done in a routine called `name_to_dev_t()`. One of the supported syntaxes is the `/dev/name` format, where the *name* is interpreted by doing a temporary mount of the `sysfs` filesystem in the `rootfs` root, and looking for a block device entry matching *name* under `/sys/block`. This process is explained in more detail [here](http://kernelnewbies.org/RootFileSystem).

The setup as described would need to be done by first booting into a minimal environment such as one provided by an `initrd`, mount the real root filesystem from `/dev/sda1` at a temporary mountpoint, e.g. `/mnt/rootfs`, then change the root directory to `/mnt/rootfs/chroot` using [`pivot_root(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pivot_root).

This is somewhat similar to how the root filesystems for *LinuX Containers* ([LXC](http://lxc.sourceforge.net)) are setup. LXC is an operating system-level virtualization implementation for Linux. Operating system-level virtualization is commonly used in virtual hosting environments as a lightweight alternative to full virtualization managed by a hypervisor. In operating system-level virtualization, a single operating system kernel is shared among multiple isolated user-space instances. Each instance, often called container, jail, *Virtual Private Server* (VPE) or *Virtual Environment* (VE), is essentially a separate operating system installation housed in a directory of its own on the host system.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, [you can do the trick using Btrfs subvolumes](http://specialmeaning.blogspot.com/2016/04/btrfs-too-booting-to-subvolume.html).

First you need to [convert ext4 to btrfs as described here](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Conversion_from_Ext3).

Convert your chroot to subvolume if it is not yet:

```
 sudo mv /path/to/chroot /path/to/chroot-tmp
 sudo btrfs subvol create /path/to/chroot
 sudo mv /path/to/chroot-tmp/* /path/to/chroot
 sudo mv /path/to/chroot-tmp/* /path/to/chroot -r # for directories
```

Now you have subvolume named **path/to/chroot**.
You can check it with `sudo btrfs subvol list /`

Now you can create boot to subvolume record in grub. Just add `rootflags=subvol=path/to/chroot` to linux kernel load string in grub menu item or use [this](https://github.com/Antynea/grub-btrfs/blob/master/41_snapshots-btrfs) to probe automatically.